# print table with vb and javascript

Tags: javascript

i am trying to print a table but i am stuck.

table name : grid 2, using asp.net & vb

this is my code for it but i made sth wrong so it opens a page with 404.

```
function printTable() {

    var printContent = document.getElementById("grid2");
    var windowUrl = 'about:blank';
    var num;
    var uniqueName = new Date();
    var windowName = 'Print' + uniqueName.getTime(); var printWindow = window.open(num, windowName, 'left=50000,top=50000,width=0,height=0');
    printWindow.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.focus();
    printWindow.print();
    printWindow.close();
}


   <p><input type="button" value="Yazdır" onClick="printTable();"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here, however none have to do with the window displaying a 404.

- Some browsers don't let you access (write into with JavaScript) `about:` pages.
- You are attempting to open a small window off-screen, which no browser will allow you to do.

Anyway this is something that is much easier done other ways than with JavaScript.

Either consider using a [print stylesheet](http://www.google.de/search?q=print+stylesheet) that hides everything that you don't want to print, or use server-side script to generate the print version of your page.